# MALLET Ranking of Words in a topic

Tags: lda, topic-modeling, mallet

I am relatively new to mallet and need to know:
- are the words in each topic that mallet produces rank ordered in some way?
- if so, what is the ordering (i.e.) is 1st in a topic list the one with the highest distribution across the corpus?

Thanks!

Comment: Can you please share the piece of Java code to get the word proportions for a particular topic?

Answer (score 5):

they are ranked based on probabilities from the training, i.e. the first word is most probable to appear in this topic, the 2nd is less probable, the 3rd less and so on.. These are not directly related to term frequencies although surely the words with highest tfidf weights are more likely to be most probable. Also, Gibbs sampling has a lot to do with how words are ranked in topics - due to randomness in sampling you can get quite different probabilities for words within topics. Try, for example, to save the model and then retrain using --input-model option - the topics will look very much alike but not the same.

That said, if you need to see actual weights of terms in the corpus unrelated to LDA, you can use something like NLTK in Python to check frequency distributions and also something like sklearn for TFIDF to get more meaningful weight distributions.